# Force HttpClient to get new version of source

Tags: c#, html, .net, http, asynchronous

I'm currently working on *something*, and it requires me to get a new version of the source each time the function is ran. Here is the code so far.

```
static class DataManager
{
    public static async void CollectData()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions 
        try
        {
            string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.lipsum.com");

            ParseHTML(responseBody);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
        }

        // Need to call dispose on the HttpClient object 
        // when done using it, so the app doesn't leak resources
        client.Dispose();
    }
    public static void ParseHTML(string _responseString)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        document.LoadHtml(_responseString);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode contrib = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'randomclass')]");

        Console.WriteLine(contrib.InnerText.Replace(",", ""));
    }
    public static void UpdateLabels(string _timer, string _participants)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to make this get a new version of the website each time I run the function.

I'm running it by typing

```
DataManager.CollectData();
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: You can compare the current version with the server version and do the necessary cleanup/update

Comment: @Praveen Paulose The problem is that it's not getting the version of the website each time I request it. I want the absolutely newest version of the site when I request it.

Comment: @user2526236 Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler() {
    CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore)
});
        try
    {
        string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.lipsum.com");

        ParseHTML(responseBody);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
    }
```

Have a look at the [HttpRequestCacheLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.httprequestcachelevel(v=vs.110).aspx) enum - there are quite a few options that may help you.